# Having hard time on understanding regex

Tags: regex, perl

After some research I still can't fully understand the Perl code below. Based on my understanding of the line

```
if ($fileName =~ /^.*\.gz\z/si)
```

the program does if `$fileName` is equal to any `.gz` then the `$fileName` will be equal to `$inputname`. Am I correct?

```
if ($fileName =~  /^.*\.gz\z/si) { 
    $filename = $inputname;
}
```

1. `/^.` - Does this means any?
2. `*\` - Does this means all?
3. `\z` - Is the `z` meaningful in a Perl regex?
4. `/si` - I do not know this either
5. `=~`- What is this mean?

I think my question is wrong too? This question to you may be simple, but to me is hard. I hope you understand.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic too narrow and unlikely to be of long term use. There are plenty of resources that offer regex debug facilities and tutorials.

Comment: If you have to ask what `=~` does then you need a Perl tutorial. You shouldn't bring questions here that are answered clearly in a language's documentation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex itself is the part between `//`.

- `^` means: beginning of the string (so no characters before).
- `.*` means: a certain amount of any character (`.` means any character, * is a quantifier, which means between 0 and infinity).
- `\.gz` means: the literal dot, followed by gz (the `.` needs to be escaped, ie preceded by a backslash `\` to mean a literal dot).
- `\z` means: "End of string".

The options are after the closing slash.(**modifiers**)

- `i` means case insensitive.
- `s` enables DOTALL mode. That is, it makes `.` to match any character whatsoever, even a newline, which normally it would not match.

Finally:

- `=~` means that it's matching the regex to the variable `$filename`.
- In conclusion, it checks the variable `$filename` to see if it contains the name of a file with a `.gz` (case-insensitive) extension.

Reference links:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html

Answer (score 3):

Basically, the regex `^.*\.gz\z/si` matches any string that ends with `.gz` (case-insensitive)... Even if the strings is several lines long!

(I would suggest removing the `s` flag—see below for meaning.)

The regex is delimited by `/` on each side. You could have used another delimiter, like `!`.

The `=~` tests if the regex is able to match the string.

**Explaining the Regex Token by Token**

- Assert position at the beginning of the string `^`
- Match any single character `.*`

  - Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) `*`
- Match the character “.” literally `\.`
- Match the character string “gz” literally (case insensitive) `gz`
- Assert position at the very end of the string `\z`

The `i` flag makes it case-insensitive. The `s` flag activates `DOTALL` mode, allowing the dot to match across lines.

Comment: This answer is fine. Why has it been down-voted?

Comment: @Borodin I think someone just downvoted all answers, since mine was also downvoted.

Comment: @AntonH yes sometimes there are random (or not?) drive-by downvote shoot-outs, the hazards of the road... :)

Comment: why remove the /s?  presumably it's there for a reason.  well, I can see doing so if you simplify the regex to the equivalent `/\.gz\z/i`

Comment: @ysth I wouldn't want to presume that the `s` there for a reason. Often people inherit regexps that are wildly inadequate. Remember that we are trying to validate a file name. The `s` turns on DOTALL, allowing the file name to span multiple lines. Does that sound right to you? Not to me, that's why I suggested removing the `s`

Comment: @zx81 yes, it does sound right.  this is a filename; there should be no reason to treat a filename containing newlines differently than any other.  the cases where you would want to use `.` *without* `/s` are few and far between.  (BTW, "DOTALL" is a Python term, I think; Perl doesn't actually have a name for it.)

Comment: @ysth 1. `DOTALL` is used in the PCRE documentation, for instance. 2. I have never seen a filename containing a newline. 3. `the cases where you would want to use . without /s are few and far between` Absolutely not my experience, which is not slight. Evidently your experience differs.